# "The values of a and of b" vs "The values of a and b"

Tags: grammar

The values of a and b = values of (a and b)

The values of a and of b = values of a and values of b

Am I correct?

Comment: What is the context of this?  In a mathematical situation, I would agree.

Comment: Natural language can be imprecise.

Comment: Second is definitely correct. For the first, in normal usage I would  read `The values of a and b `  to have the same sense as _value of a and value of b_. In maths  my default assumption would be that (a and b) will give a single True/False value unless a and b are vectors.